# Apache Karaf - How to start several bundles simultaneously?

Tags: talend, apache-karaf

I'm using Apache Karaf to deploy routes and web services created on Talend Runtime ESB, via OSGI Bundles.
When I restart Karaf, I've noticed that routes are starting one by one, after the previous one has finished. They all have the start level at 90.
On a server with two hundred routes, it takes more than 30 minutes to start all routes.

Is there any way to start routes faster? 5 by 5 for example? I've read the entire doc and haven't seen any parameter on this. I've tested to change the JVM parameter java.security.egd with no visible effect.

Thanks.

Comment: You can edit start level of bundles. What happens if you have several different start levels ? Does it speed up the deployment ? command is bundle:start-level <bundleId> <XX>

Comment: No, it doesn't speed up deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you are using Eclipse BluePrint, but if you are I ran into the same issue a few years ago.

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1099719/

It basically means that BluePrint starts all bundles in a single thread, causing the exact behaviour you are describing.